Relational database common values
What is proper way to design common values in relational database?
Example - table car_make:



id
name




1
Opel


2
BMW



Table car_model:



id
name
make_id




1
Astra
1


2
Vectra
1


3
I7
2


4
X4
2


5
Other
?



In that example I want every make to have additional "Other" model despite its models.
If we omit the "Other" value, one-many relationship seems to be the most logical because every make has it own models. But if we introduce many-to-many relationship for say thousands of makes just to have the "Other" model for every make, won't it be waste of resources?

Every "other" should be unique to its "make". I don't see how a many to many relationship comes into play because models are specific to maker.  The common "other" category doesn't make unknown models equivalent. An Opel other will never be the same as a BMW other.

Given my previous comment, why not leave out an "other" category and allow model to be NULL in your application, such that NULLs aren't equivalent?

It depends on how you're planning to query the database in the application. As far as I concern, "other" model is only relevant when you group the query for each car_make, for example when you're trying to aggregate the sales for each car_make and its correponding car_models. If you're consistent about the naming convention of "other" as a car_model in each car_make, you can also filter the query using that name, for example: "Other" with capital O.
About waste of resource, let's try to compare between many-to-many and one-to-many. In many-to-many, we need to introduce an intermediary table, let's call it car_model_x_make. Also, to give you a perspective on how handful querying a many-to-many relationship is, here's an example on getting the car_models created by BMW.
SELECT 
  car_model.name 
FROM car_make,car_model_x_make,car_model 
WHERE 
  car_make.id=car_model_x_make.makeid AND 
  car_model.id=car_model_x_make.modelid AND 
  car_make.name='BMW'

If you have 1000 makes, and each make is populated with 10 unique models, plus one "other" model, this means the car_make table will have 1000 rows of 2 essential columns, car_model will have 10001 rows of 2 essential columns, and car_model_x_make will have 11000 rows of 3 essential columns. All in all, there would be 55002 essential cells.
In comparison, one-to-many relationship will only populate your database with 35000 essential cells, which consist of 1000 rows of 2 essential columns in car_make, and 11000 rows of 3 essential columns in car_model.

Please wake up, your way of combining tables ended in 1992. It's 2024 now. Search for JOIN!

Thanks for response. I want users possibility to display all models for selected make and other option in case if ceratin model does not exist. Also as you said I want to aggregate models by make to make some statistics. I think about the one-many relation, but I'm still not sure if it is too much duplication if ever make have its own "other" model.

@JonasMetzler, of course it's not the recommended way. It's just an expression of a complication with many to many query compared to one to many. Performance wise, it's not that much different from INNER JOIN, btw. Look it up!

@PoCiTo, well, if you really want to explore the modern data types in today's SQL standards, you can try JSON. That way, you can mix the traits of both worlds, SQL and noSQL.
